# Weird Error screen in ASP.net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

I am working on some ASP.NET Application. In case of some breakdown or error, I am getting some weird error screen. The error page shows something like:

```
��`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@�������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{����{����;�N'���?
\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"��Ey�')=��y6�����h��贮
�:�V�˼n��E:��,m�Wy�����<�ӶJ�e;~|W^�`4�u�A:�f��/>
```

and so on....

The application is currently in test phase so, I have left the error screen visible from web.config. Anyone who have faced the same issue, and got the problem and solution for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out whether the ASP.NET application you are working on utilizes some form of automatic GZip compression, your error page is very reminiscent of what Rick Strahl describes here: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/02/ASPNET-GZip-Encoding-Caveats. There is also a solution in that blog post.

Comment: Yes, you are correct I am using HTTP Compression (GZIP), and thanks for the solution as well. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Rick Strahl for the solution, and @Andrew Sklyarevsky for referring :D

Reference and Complete Description: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/02/ASPNET-GZip-Encoding-Caveats

I solved the issue, and thus the solution, is adding following codes to `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Remove any special filtering especially GZip filtering
    Response.Filter = null;
…
}
```

Or even better

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
{
// ensure that if GZip/Deflate Encoding is applied that headers are set
// also works when error occurs if filters are still active
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
if (response.Filter is GZipStream && response.Headers["Content-encoding"] != "gzip")
    response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
else if (response.Filter is DeflateStream && response.Headers["Content-encoding"] != "deflate")
    response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
}
```